# Userdefault error with Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I tried save array to UserDefault but got error with Attempt to set a non-property-list object. I know how to use UserDefault since last year but at this time, something is new to me that I haven't experience save the array with multiple string. What is best way to save array into UserDefaults? I tried look around online but most of them are old swift and they doesn't look like my array. Here my code:

```
var currentWeatherUnit: [(temperature:String, measurement:String)])] = []

func checkingForSetting(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
   if let getsetting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Current Weather Setting") {
      currentWeatherUnit = getsetting as! [(temperature: String, measurement: String)]
      print("Current weather setting is exist")
   } else {
   currentWeatherUnit = [(temperature: "C", measurement: "mm")]
      UserDefaults.standard.set(currentWeatherUnit, forKey: "Current Weather Setting")
      print("Create new setting for current weather")
   }
}
```

Crash Log:

> 2020-06-19 16:32:17.354822-0600 Playground Phy[5800:1787752] [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
>       "(temperature: \"C\", measurement: \"mm\")"
>   ) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key Current Weather Setting
>   2020-06-19 16:32:17.355108-0600 Playground Phy[5800:1787752] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
>       "(temperature: \"C\", measurement: \"mm\")"
>   ) for key Current Weather Setting'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x193cda300 0x1939eec1c 0x193d335a8 0x193d07ab4 0x193d08190 0x193d07e7c 0x193d08250 0x193baffb0 0x193d10838 0x193c403bc 0x193c3fc04 0x193bac83c 0x193baf9d4 0x193d13cc8 0x193fda118 0x104464dc0 0x104464140 0x104464928 0x1977b0aac 0x1977b5660 0x1977b5a4c 0x197e5c264 0x197e5b960 0x197e5c8f0 0x197e6db44 0x198072a10 0x1973f8a2c 0x197e1ef9c 0x197e1f320 0x1979a1e08 0x198f3cffc 0x198f635a0 0x198f47ebc 0x198f63234 0x1049d718c 0x1049da964 0x198f896c4 0x198f89370 0x198f898dc 0x193c55af4 0x193c55a48 0x193c55198 0x193c4ff38 0x193c4f8f4 0x19e066604 0x197e23358 0x10446baec 0x193acb2dc)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error message carefully, it's pretty clear.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object ( "(temperature: \"C\", measurement: \"mm\")" ) for key Current Weather Setting'

The list object is a **tuple** which is not property list compliant.

A reasonable solution is a custom struct and `Codable`, the completion handler is pointless because `UserDefaults` is synchronous.

```
struct WeatherUnit : Codable {
    let temperature, measurement : String
}

var currentWeatherUnit = [WeatherUnit]()

func checkingForSetting() {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Current Weather Setting") {
        do {
            currentWeatherUnit = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([WeatherUnit].self, from: data)
            print("Current weather setting is exist")
        } catch { print(error) }
    } else {
        currentWeatherUnit = [WeatherUnit(temperature: "C", measurement: "mm")]
        let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(currentWeatherUnit)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Current Weather Setting")
        print("Create new setting for current weather")
    }
}
```